# display bar chart using googlechart

Tags: php, json, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to display barchart in php and mysql using google chart.

Here is my code

```
<?php

include('header.php');

?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Leads'],
         /* ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]*/


            <?php echo implode(",", $myurl); 
             echo $myurl;
            ?>

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Sales Graph',
          vAxis: {title: 'Sales',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>


            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">

     <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['whatt']);
    $query = "SELECT YEAR(last_modified) as year, MONTH(last_modified) as month, COUNT(id) as count
              FROM leads
              WHERE lead_customer ='{$type}'
              GROUP BY year, month
              ORDER BY year, month";
              echo $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       // echo "Year: {$row['year']}, Month: {$row['month']}, Count: {$row['count']}<br>\n";

        $myurl[] = "['".$row['month']."', ".$row['count']."]";

    }


 print_r($myurl);
echo implode(",", $myurl);

}

?>



<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

But i am getting error **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**.
I checked my query and it is right. But i am not getting why the chart is not getting displayed.

Please suggest where i am going wrong.

**HTM Data**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Leads'],




        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Sales Graph',
          vAxis: {title: 'Sales',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML output?

Comment: out put is `SELECT YEAR(last_modified) as year, MONTH(last_modified) as month, COUNT(id) as count FROM leads WHERE lead_customer ='Lead' GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year, monthArray ( [0] => ['9', 2] ) ['9', 2]`
Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: This isn't the HTML output i'm looking for. Use F12 to get your html output and paste everything between your `script` tags.

Comment: I have pasted the HTML output above with my original post. Its giving blank :(

Comment: So `$myurl` is empty. That means you didn't define it. Try to cut the `drawChart` javascript and paste it after the `isset($_POST['submit'])` if statement.

Comment: Hey... so silly mistake i did :(. Sorry and thank you for your precious time. It worked properly! Thank you very much